# How to set base size for rem

Tags: css

I have a simple question, where do you declare the base size that `rem` is calculated from?

```
<body>
  <h1>Something</h1>
</body>
```

I can see that the `font-size` is `<body>` is set to 16px and the `<h1>` is set to `3rem`, yet the font is rendering at 30px when I'd expect 48px.  Can any parent redefine the base?

Comment: `rem` is relative to the root element, which is the `html` element

Answer (score 115, accepted):

> **rem**
>
> Represents the font-size of the root element (typically `<html>`).
> When used within the root element font-size, it represents its initial
> value (a common browser default is 16px, but user-defined preferences
> may modify this).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

---

In other words, change the **font size of your `html` element**, and the calculation base for `rem` will change.

Example:

```html
<html style="font-size: 10px">
...
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to override it?  I understand that kind of defeats the purpose, but a bunch of other elements will be screwed up if I change that.

Comment: You can use `em` instead, which relates to the font size of the parent element.

Comment: "Override that"...um, that's what setting font-size on `html` is doing...

Comment: Depending on the browser you might get different results. For example, i am using FF on a mac, 3rem computes to 52.8px when the base is 16px

Comment: Maybe you can do it using some js?

Answer (score 28):

`rem` units are based on the font-size of the `html` element, not the `body` element. The default size is *usually* 16px on html, however that's not guaranteed, and users can change that default value. A common practice is to manually set the font-size explicitly on html, usually to that 16px value, and then use rems in other places to set the final display value.

However, that practice has accessibility problems for when users want or need to increase the default font size, so you should design your pages and layouts so that they can adapt to different sizes.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size:

> rem values are relative to the root html element, not the parent element. In other words, it lets you specify a font size in a relative fashion without being affected by the size of the parent, thereby eliminating compounding.

Answer (score 5):

Just set the font size for the `html` element:

```css
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

You are setting the root font size when you do this so the `rem` measurement will be influenced by this when setting a font size.

Comment: You are setting the root font size when you do this so the rem mesurement will be influenced by this when setting a font size

Comment: That's the kind of thing you should put in your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32307582)

Answer (score 4):

To add a best practice to previous answers: root font size should be expressed as a percentage.

```
html {
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

This practice scales the font relative to the users system/browser settings. Your site will be consistently sized up/down compared to other websites. (assuming those websites also follow best practices).

Even more respectful to the user is to not touch the root font size at all so that they have a consistent reading experience across websites and can reliably use accessibility settings.

Answer (score 2):

Set the font size for the `html` element as follows. The default font size for the `html` element is 16px. `rem` base size is always set on the `html` element not `body`.

```html
<html style="font-size:16px">
<body>
     <h1>Rem Sizing</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great formatting for a first post!

Answer (score 0):

Root element of page is html, we need to specify Size of this element as we need all other sizes will be in rem unit
The default font size for the html element is 16px which will considered as 1rem.

SCSS based Example:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px; /* you can chose any size here 16 is default */
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    font-size: 62.5%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 45%;
  }
}
```

you can adjust percentage according to your use case