# Change fonts size automatically in React Native WebView using Dynamic Type (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, react-native-webview

I maintain a hybrid **react-native** (**0.66.3**) mobile app, which is basically a shell which wraps around our web apps very nicely. This method where we develop once and reuse on mobile and web platforms suits our use cases perfectly.

I noticed an issue in accessibility very recently. iOS has an accessibility feature to allow users to select their preferred text size which helps users who need larger text for better readability.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically)

Unfortunately, the iOS version of our hybrid react-native app doesn’t respect this setting and doesn't change its text size appropriately. The shell (native part) of the iOS app picks up the font size from dynamic type but the WebView (**react-native-webview: 7.5.1**) component in the iOS app doesn’t pick up the font size from dynamic type.

Is this a known issue/thing in “react-native-webview” or else could someone please kindly point me in the right direction (probably with an example) to add this accessibility feature to the iOS app?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this isn't currently (Nov 22) supported by react-native-webview.

[react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getfontscale) has a function called getFontScale() you could potentially use this to [set the base rem value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451764/how-to-set-base-size-for-rem) and then inject that into your webview ie.

```
  async function getInjectedJs() {
    const fontScale = await getGetFontScale();

   return `
     const html  = document.getElementByTagName('html');
     html.style.fontSize = {your_base_font_size} * ${fontScale}
   `
  }

  ...


  <WebView injectJavascriptAfterLoad={getInjectedJs()) ...
```

The above won't quite work but you get the idea.

Keen to hear if you've found a different way