# How to reset the global font size of Vaadin Flow 24.1 to the font size settings of Vaadin Flow 24.0?

Tags: vaadin, font-size, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

After updating to Vaadin Flow 24.1, the global font size of all texts has changed and is now smaller than before (usable, but not desired). How can I reset the font size back to the original value (from Vaadin Flow 24.0)? Or how can I change the font size globally for Vaadin Flow?

I looked in the changelogs of the new update but found nothing that mentions this issue. I hope you have some suggestions about this problem.

**Update on the above issue**. There seems to be a pull request for this problem which hopefully fixes it in the next patch. (https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/17070)

Comment: Check this ticket: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/17070

Comment: Thank you for providing the issue. I did not see that yet^^

Answer (score 0):

In our case the issue was caused because we set the value of `--lumo-font-size-m` to a value different than `1rem`. Due to a change in how CSS is loaded in Vaadin 24.1 this value is now applied to the `font-size` of the `html` tag, which resets the base `font-size` for the entire dom tree.

See [How to set base size for rem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451764/how-to-set-base-size-for-rem)

For now we worked around the issue by adding the following block of CSS to our `styles.css` file of our theme

```
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```